# streaming 2 cameras at the same time in python with ip camera support

Tags: python, opencv

I want to be able to capture 2 cameras or more by python to apply some object detection code. I want to use the laptops default cam and in another frame an IP camera that has a domain address. I can plug by USB another cam and 2 frames pop and it works fine. but when I try to alter the code so that it takes the IP cam I get this error:

*ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)*

this is the code for streaming 2 or more cameras

```
import urllib.request
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2

video_capture_0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
video_capture_1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    
    ret0, frame0 = video_capture_0.read()
    ret1, frame1 = video_capture_1.read()
    

    if (ret0):
        cv2.imshow('Cam 0', frame0)

    if (ret1):
        cv2.imshow('Cam 1', frame1)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture_0.release()
video_capture_1.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and this is the code to stream the IP camera

```
import urllib.request
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
URL = "http://10.28.193.74:8080/shot.jpg"
while True:
    img_arr = np.array(bytearray(urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read()),dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(img_arr,-1)
    cv2.imshow('IPWebcam',img)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break;

    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And here is my lousy attempt at merging the codes

```
import urllib.request
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
URL = "http://10.28.193.74:8080/shot.jpg"
video_capture_0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret0, frame0 = video_capture_0.read()
    img_arr = np.array(bytearray(urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read()),dtype=np.uint8)
    ret1, img = cv2.imdecode(img_arr,-1)

    if (ret0):
        
        cv2.imshow('Cam 0', frame0)

    if (ret1):

        cv2.imshow('IPWebcam',img)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a first glance cv2.imdecode doesn't return a value for ret1

video_capture.read() will return two values:
a boolean which represents whether the frame was read successfully
and a numpy matrix containing the frame

It only returns a numpy matrix of the image, therefore you can only unpack one value, and not 2

you can replace `if(ret1):` with `if(img is not None):` maybe to check whether the frame from the ip camera is not rubbish